# Select, Modify and insert into the same table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

What's the easiest way to select a row, modify couple of columns and insert it to the same table? 
I'm trying to insert a new row based on another.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3)
SELECT column1, 'no', column3 FROM table2 WHERE column2 = 'yes'
```

Hopefully this is a bit clearer as to how you do this. As you can see, I've grabbed two columns from table2 and for the other column I used a text value for instead of the value for column2.

Other patterns you can use:

Combine a column and some other text (Assumes the column is already a string data type.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2)
SELECT column1 + 'no', column2 FROM table2 WHERE column2 = 'yes'
```

Combine a column and some text, One example where the column is a string and one where it is not.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2)
SELECT column1 + 'no', 'A' + cast(column2 as Varchar (10)) FROM table2 WHERE column2 = 'yes'
```

Comment: Ther is no circumstance in which you should use wildcards in an insert

Comment: How to do the same thing but with a small modification. Ex: i want to insert 'column2 val + test' instead of 'no' i mean to insert value from the swlwcted row with a text appended.

Comment: @Shashank.gupta40 I know this is old, but for reference, provided that column2 is a 'string' type (varchar, nvarchar, etc), you can append a value by treating the column name like a variable and appending a new string, e.g. `column2 + 'test'`.

Comment: Note: In the example given, if the criterion " column2 = 'yes' " returns many rows, then many rows will get inserted.  This can be quite handy, but the orig poster did ask about just one row, so this note is a caution.

Comment: Without the `SELECT 'no'` and `WHERE column2 = 'yes'` we would get into an infinite loop.

Comment: if my table have 40 columns, do I need to write all of then? because the first example fit for me, but I need to change just 1 of 40 columns

Answer (score 7):

```
INSERT INTO table(column1,column2) SELECT column1, const2 FROM table ...
```

The select list will likely mix copied columns (by name) and changed columns (by desired values).

Comment: Just to clarify, do your modifications as part of the select portion of the statement.

Comment: It depends on your needs.  For example.  Suppose your primary key is a meaningless integer with column name id without any key allocation mechanism (such as autoincrementing column); suppose that you want to copy the value of column1 from record with ID passed as @source, and set the value of column2 to a new value passed as @param.  Then execute the following with the two parameters: `INSERT INTO t(id, column1, column2) SELECT m.id + 1, source.column1, @param FROM t m, t source WHERE source.id = @source AND m.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM t)`

Comment: @Agzam - If, on the other hand, the id column is autoincrementing, it is all much simpler: `INSERT INTO t(column1, column2) SELECT source.column1, @param FROM t source WHERE source.id = @source`

Answer (score 2):

Say column is int

```
INSERT INTO table(column1,column2) SELECT column1 + 1, column2 -1 FROM table
```

You can multiply columns and perform string functions.

Comment: How do you solve the case where there table is empty in the first place?