# Insert data with one param difference to the same SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I would like to copy data from table a and insert it to the same table with a difference in one column.

For example: I have table a, with column name, I would like to :

```
insert into table a (name = 'daniel')
select * from table a  where phone = '000'
```

I would like the tran to take all columns in table a which phone is '000'
and insert them again into table a the same, only the column name would be different.

Thank you

Comment: You can make use of loop and @Variable to get this done. Give it a try, if you find any issues post it here. we can help you out.

Comment: `select a, b ,c, 'daniel', e, f from table a ...` just replacing the `name` column.

Comment: If the name is static `Daniel` for all records, you can do proceed with what @AlexK.has mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope i understood the problem, if so here is the solution:

INSERT INTO table2 (column1, name, column3)
SELECT column1, 'daniel', column3 FROM table2 WHERE phone = '000'

useful links:

[Select, Modify and insert into the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879830/select-modify-and-insert-into-the-same-table)

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Kindly let me your thoughts or feedbacks 
thanks

karthik

Answer (score 0):

Ya you can do with below lines

insert into table a (name )
select  a.columa+' ' +b.columb as name from table a  where phone = '000

If column have more Columbus than you can concate more Colums and insert into single column

Answer (score 0):

My code by the answer :

```
select * from CatalogItems where UserId = 31406

begin tran
INSERT INTO CatalogItems (UserId,Code,Name,Price,PriceAfterTax,VatPercentage )
SELECT '31429',Code,Name,Price,PriceAfterTax,VatPercentage
 from CatalogItems WHERE userid  = 31406

 commit
```