# How do I INSERT new row as copy of previous and UPDATE old row value in mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

I am looking for a simple approach to solve my current challenge. I have the following table:

```
Id Location DateFrom   DateTo     RateType     Rate 
1  LA       01/01/2017 01/01/2018 AverageRate  18
```

A few mysql commands in my code behind to select these values and display them to textboxes/datepickers:

```
public partial class MainWindow : 
{
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    string connectionString = "datasource= ;port=3306;username= ;password= ";
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    MySqlCommand sAR = new MySqlCommand("Select Amount from Daily.Rates where RateType = 'Average Hourly Wages'", connection);
    MySqlCommand sARF = new MySqlCommand("Select DateFrom from Daily.Rates where RateType = 'Average Hourly Wages'", connection);
    MySqlCommand sART = new MySqlCommand("Select DateTo from Daily.Rates where RateType = 'AverageRate'", connection);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        txtAR.Text = sAHW.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        dfAR.Text = sAHWF.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        dtAR.Text = sAHWT.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

**What I am trying to achieve:**

If I need to increase the rate to 20 I want to keep the old rate of 18, add a copy of that row with the updated values and change the DateTo field as follows: new DateFrom - 1. Basically if I change the rate today I want to end up with this:

```
Id Location DateFrom   DateTo                 RateType     Rate
1  LA       01/01/2017 10/11/2017(DateFrom-1) AverageRate  18
2  LA       10/12/2017 01/01/2018             AverageRate  20
```

I have quite a few textxboxes that might not change so if none of the values have changed, I don't want to insert a new row, just keep the old values. What would be the best approach to write this query? How can I efficiently combine an if statement with Insert, Update and Select and what I already have in the textboxes in order to achieve my goal? Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the rowID of the old row?

Comment: The row Id for the old row is 1. I am not selecting it although I think it might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible repeat of [Select Modify and Insert into the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879830/select-modify-and-insert-into-the-same-table)

You will need two queries, since there is an `INSERT` and an `UPDATE`. To make sure you don't get race conditions, you will have to do it in a `TRANSACTION`. For this, I suggest a Stored Procedure.

Assuming your input values are `DateFrom` and `NewRate` and `OldRate` and that `Id` field auto-increments:

```
delimiter #

CREATE PROCEDURE Keep_Old_Row
(
IN p_DateFrom DATETIME, 
IN p_NewRate INT,
IN p_OldRate INT
)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO Daily.Rates
(Location, DateFrom,   DateTo,     RateType,     Rate  )
SELECT Location, p_DateFrom, DateTo, RateType, p_NewRate 
FROM Daily.Rates
WHERE Rate=p_OldRate;

UPDATE Daily.Rates
SET DateTo=DATE_SUB(p_Date_From, INTERVAL 1 DAY), Rate=p_NewRate
WHERE Rate=p_OldRate;

END#

delimiter ;
```

***HOWEVER***, you will need the other fields, so:

```
INSERT INTO Daily.Rates
(Location, DateFrom,   DateTo,     RateType,     Rate [,... Other Fields]  )
SELECT Location, p_DateFrom, DateTo, RateType, p_NewRate  [,... Other Fields]
```

is really what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much Jacques. Your example is really concise and it helped me a lot. I had to remove Rate=p_NewRate from the Update query in order to keep the old rate the same. The solution works great! Hat off to you!