# MySQL insert with value from select

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have this query:

```sql
INSERT INTO oc_stock_hpp (product_id, buy_price) 
VALUES (
'3337',
(SELECT buy_price
FROM oc_stock_hpp
WHERE product_id ='3337'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1)
)
```

I get an error:

> Table 'oc_stock_hpp' is specified twice, both as a target for 'INSERT' and as a separate source for data

What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select, Modify and insert into the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879830/select-modify-and-insert-into-the-same-table)

Comment: Why would you want to duplicate the most recent row for product_id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an insert-select statement and add the product_id to the query:

```sql
INSERT INTO oc_stock_hpp (product_id, buy_price) 
SELECT   product_id, buy_price
FROM     oc_stock_hpp 
WHERE    product_id = '3337'
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```